# Cannot deploy with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my first app with rails. I'm unable to deploy it, and I'm unhappy because the framework itself allowed me to develop really quickly the application, but I've only two days to make the deployment work :-(

I've installed and configured passenger following a tutorial (i'm using RVM).
When I access the page I have the following error page: [traceback here](http://pastebin.com/SpYLP2Db) (posted on pastebin to keep this post clear).

What is wrong?
i just uploaded the whole project on the production server, ran `bundle install`, `rake db:create` `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed`. Am I missing some step?

Why it doesn't run?
Developed using Rails 3.2.3 with Ruby 1.9.3.

Please help me to get it running.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: looks like you have some problem in home/regroup/calendar/app/models/event.rb you can paste it here

Comment: Sure! It contains [this code](http://pastebin.com/SXXk1URn)

Comment: The fact is that on my PC that i've used to develop it (ubuntu) it runs properly using `rails s`.

Comment: thats the problem check my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have very little  information about your problem but I have and idea what is going on. Check your belongs_to association in your event model if there is a `class` parameter replace it with `class_name`.

Comment: Awesome! It's finally running! Thank you so much!
I spent 2 days working on this... Rails is awesome but the traceback is a bit confusing :-s

Why is this working different from the development machine?

Now I just discovered that templates are not inheriting (devise template is not inheriting) from the layout you can see the application [here](http://agenda.gestiregroup.com/). It's me or I'm finding any kind of issue deploying this app? :-S
Then when logging in it says "we're sorry but something went weong".
I'm going to read the log. Get back to you in a minute.

Comment: Sure, it solved the issue. Many many thanks :-)
Can you help me to fix [this last one error](http://pastebin.com/NeTP49dp)? It's cleanly missing the `.haml` templates searching for `.erb` instead, but dunno why. Bundle install correctly installed Haml.
Do I need to set some configuration in production to make it work?

Comment: it would be good if you write a new question and also paste there your Gemfile

Comment: Ok, I'll do it ;)
Have a nice day!